# What's the best way to send the data from a Repl.it to my backend?

Tags: python, vue.js

I'm storing Python code in my DB as plain text. I want to fetch it, edited in the frontend, and then post it back to the DB. If relevant, this is inside a Vue project.

I've seen alternatives such as Repl.it. It partially solves the problem: You can edit a piece of code, it gets saved on Repl.it's backend.

But I want to save such code as plain text on my DB. How can I do that?

Is Repl.it not the best alternative at all? I thought about placing everything in a  tag. But ideally, the code would be written in an IDE-kind of environment. That's why I thought about Repl.it.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to *run* the code in the browser after fetching it? If so, yes, try a service like [glitch](https://glitch.com), [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.com), etc

If you only want to show it and edit it, use a rich text input, hopefully with code highlighting.

Comment: It would be cool to run it in the browser, but not critical. I haven't looked at glitch or codesandbox. But I suspect the same problem exists.